# Samsung oven trips breaker

Tags: oven

I have a Samsung stove and when I preheat the oven, it trips the breaker several minutes into use. The breaker is hot, but when it cools down, it can be turned on. The cook top works after the breaker is turned back on. The cook top doesn't trip the breaker, only the oven.

Comment: What model and kW rating is the stove, what amp rating is the breaker, and can you get access to an amp-clamp (i.e. clampmeter)?  Also, I take it the oven will trip the breaker with no other loads, yet the stove won't, even if you stick your 4 biggest pots full of water on the burners and turn them up to MAX?  Oh, and one more thing: if you just stick stuff in the oven and turn it on, does it trip then, or only if you preheat it with nothing inside?

Comment: Some ovens "preheat" by turning on both bake & broil elements at the same time. Whether the controls **allow** you to just set it to bake (using only the bake element) and NOT have it do "special speedy preheat mode" will vary by oven.  In any case, it certainly appears that your service to the stove might be underrated, but the details requested are needed to examine that case.

Comment: What brand / type of service panel do you have? I have seen breakers get hot that had bad contacts, the heat was enough to trip the thermal trip in the breaker. If it is a bad contact this can permanently damage the buss so it should be checked to verify that a bad contact is not the problem.

Comment: Does the breaker have a TEST button on it?